# CellLabel alignment issues in version 13.2

Tags: front-end, cells, version-13.2

I found that when the global magnification is set to 75% and the number on the CellLabel is larger, there will be alignment issues. Below is a comparison to version 12.2
[image]

I tried to change some settings,

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, CellLabelPositioning -> Left];
```

`CellLabelPositioning -> Left`  have some useful, but it brings new problems. For TraditionalForm, the label display is incomplete, and `CellLabelPositioning -> Automatic`  is more reasonable in this case.

[image]

I also tried to modify CellLabelStyle, but not all celllabels are effective.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,CellLabelPositioning->Automatic,CellLabelStyle->Directive["CellLabel",8.6]];
```

[image]
Do you have a better way?